# Rate limit a function while holding a button

Tags: android, chromecast

```
    // RIGHT BUTTON
    Button btnRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRight);
    btnRight.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                API_send_movement("move_right");
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                API_send_movement("stop_right");
            }
            return false; // This will enable players to drag their finger
        }

    });
```

**Purpose:** To have a player drag their finger across some buttons, up, left and right. That is why it returns false.

This works great!

**Question:** How do I 'rate limit' this? Currently it sends a signal every tick, and needs to be slowed down to say, once every 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to set a `long lastCall;` variable that stores the last time `API_send_movement("move_right");` is called, and return immediately if the time difference isn't big enough. Something along the line of:

```
// RIGHT BUTTON 
Button btnRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRight);
btnRight.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
    long lastCall;

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(lastCall + 500 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            return false;
        }

        lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            API_send_movement("move_right"); 
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            API_send_movement("stop_right"); 
        } 
        return false; // This will enable players to drag their finger 
    } 

});
```

Comment: Confirmed. THANK YOU very much. I'm new to Java.